# Android facebook sent status, get response "Feed action request limit reached"

Tags: android, facebook

My code:

```
public void postOnWall(String msg) {
     try {
            String response = facebookClient.request("me");
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("message", msg);
            response = facebookClient.request("me/feed", parameters, 
                    "POST");
            Log.e("Tests", "got response: " + response);
            if (response == null || response.equals("") || 
                    response.equals("false")) {
               Log.e("Error", "Blank response");
            }
     } catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

my error:

**08-19 17:45:20.774: ERROR/Tests(5118): got response: {"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#341) Feed action request limit reached"}}**

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're rate-limiting the number of "Feed actions" you can take.  Basically they don't want your app spamming people's walls, so they limit the number of times you can do this.

For testing, you should use a [test user](https://developers.new.facebook.com/docs/test_users), which has higher limits.

Answer (score 0):

Snippet from http://www.facebook.com/insights/ => click diagnostics to
see ur app requests limit.

> Based on the affinity users show for your apps use of Facebook
>   Platform through their interactions, your app is allocated certain
>   abilities and limits. This is the functionality currently allocated to
>   your app. These values will change over time depending on how users
>   interact with your app. All integration points have a set of limit
>   values and the threshold bucket column tells you which of these limits
>   buckets your app is in for that integration point. Bucket 1 is the
>   smallest allocation bucket.